# ui-sref and ui-view Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs

If user is not registered, register. I want to show registration form using ui-sref and ui-view.

included **scripts** :

```
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/build/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/signup/signup-controller.js"></script>
```

In the app.js defined **state**

```
(function () {
  angular.module('TimeWaste', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('signUp', {
        url : "/signup",
        templateUrl : "app/signup/signup.html",
        controller : "SignUpController"
      })
  })
}());
```

Then i have this html code in my **index.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="login.email">
        <input type="text" ng-model="login.password">
        <button>Login</button>
        <a ui-sref="signUp">Create</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div ui-view></div>
```

Link is disabled, a view not loads....
Some help ?

Comment: Is it inside another view?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,

```
.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('signUp', {
      url : "/signup",
      views: {
        "container@": {
          templateUrl: "app/signup/signup.html",
          controller: "SignUpController"
        }
      },
  })
})
```

Then put name on your ui-view

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="login.email">
      <input type="text" ng-model="login.password">
      <button>Login</button>
      <a ui-sref="signUp">Create</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div ui-view="container"></div>
```

ui-sref doesn't know which ui-view it will load because your ui-view and ui-sref is not on the same parent node. check on multiple and named views here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Hmmm, i can access file(view) using http://localhost:3000/app/signup/signup.html
I think it is something wrong with a reference ??